# How many integer solutions to this 5 integers equation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Ref to the question in [Unusual 5th grade problem, how to solve it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290435/unusual-5th-grade-problem-how-to-solve-it/292155#292155).

Find a positive integer solution $(x,y,z,a,b)$ for which

$$\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = 1\;.$$

Here is my question: 
  How many solutions for this question?

There was a C++ program for the answer under 100. But you can easily find answer outside 100, as [x:5, y:220, z:4, a:2, b:22].

I can find 2477 answers for number <= 1806. When we change the upper limit, are there more answers? Is the total number of solutions limited? I guess so, but not able to prove it. Can you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of solutions is limited. In fact, the largest possible value for the variables would arise from the greedy algorithm (choosing the largest possible $\frac{1}{n}$ each time), which gives

$$ 1 =\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{43} + \frac {1}{ 1806}$$

Hence, you're done (assuming that your calculations are correct).

As to how to show that the greedy algorithm yields the largest possible value, read up on the [Sylvester Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence).