# Find positive, coprime integers whose reciprocals sum to 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions

Reading [*"Find five positive integers whose reciprocals sum to 1"*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290435/find-five-positive-integers-whose-reciprocals-sum-to-1), I wondered whether it is possible to find

> Reciprocals of pairwise coprime, positive integers that sum to 1.

We can find reciprocals of arbitrary length that sum to 1 by applying the following rules to get longer sequences from shorter ones:

We have $\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac1{n(n+1)}$ and thus

$$\frac1n = \frac1{n+1} + \frac1{n(n+1)}
\qquad (1)$$

and we have the trivial

$$\frac1n = \underbrace{\frac1{kn} + \frac1{kn} +\cdots}_{k \text{ times}}
\qquad (2.k)$$

The *coprime* condition implies that all denominators must be pairwise unequal, and we can achieve that by applying the splitting rules above to get sequences of arbitrary length.  For example, apply 3 times rule (2.2) and rule (1) once to get a sequence of length 5 with 5 different denominators:
$$\begin{align}
1 &= \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \frac18 \\
&= \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \frac19 + \frac1{72}
\end{align}$$

However, these replacement rules will always produce at least 2 denominators that are not coprime to each other.

> Is there a proof that coprime, egyptian partitions of unity do not exist?

For example, the thread linked above has an answer with a computer generated [list of egyptian partitions of length 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/292155/746312), but as far as I can see, all partitions have at least one pair with $\gcd\geqslant2$.

In the case such partitions to not exist (or only finitely many of them), then: Are there coprime, egyptian partitions for each natural number? (Excluding 1 as a denominator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the integers are $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$.

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}=1$

$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\prod_{j\neq i}{a_j}}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}=1$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\prod_{j\neq i}{a_j}}= \prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}$

$\prod_{j \neq 1}{a_j}+ \sum_{i=2}^{n}{\prod_{j\neq i}{a_j}}= \prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_i} $

The first term of the left hand side of the equation is the only one not divisible by $a_1$. Therefore such sets of reciprocals do not exist.

Comment: Why is it not divisible by $a_1$? I did not request the numbers to be prime, just to be pairwise coprime.  Just the fact that $a_1$ does not occur in the product does not mean the product is not divisible by $a_1$?

Comment: pairwise co - prime means that none of the other integers is divisible by any factor of $a_1$.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see.