# Given a rational number $p/q$, show that the equation $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{p}{q}$ has only finite many positive integer solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

How can i solve this,

Given a rational number $p/q$, show that the equation $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{p}{q}$ has only finite  many positive integer solutions.

I thought let $\frac pq=\frac1r$, but solving this gets $(x-r)(y-r)=r^2$, which gives the no. of solutions to be $k(r^2)$ where $k(r^2)$ is the no. of divisors of $r$.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109655/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG you may assume $\frac{1}{x}$ $\geq$ $\frac{1}{y}$.

Then $\frac{1}{x}\geq\frac{1}{2}.\frac{p}{q}$ so $\frac{2p}{q}\geq x$.

There are only finite many positive integers no larger than $2p/q$, also for each $x$ there is only one $y$ ,therefore there are finite solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

**Case 1:** If $x \leq y$ then

$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} \leq \frac{2}{x}$$

Then $x \leq \frac{2q}{p}$. There are only finitely many integers $x$, and for each $x$ there exists at most one $y$ so that $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{p}{q}$.

**Case 2:** If $x > y$ then

Copy the above solution but with $y$ and $x$ interchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the equation equivalent to $(x-r)(y-r)=r^2$ is $$(px-q)(py-q)=q^2$$ Which gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A solution always satisfies
$$ \frac{x + y}{xy} = \frac{p}{q} $$.

Conclude that $xy = r q$ for some positive integer $r$. Now what?